# Worker pool where certain tasks can only be done by certain workers

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, process, threadpool

I have a lot of tasks that I'd like to execute a few at a time.  The normal solution for this is a thread pool.  However, my tasks need resources that only certain threads have.  So I can't just farm a task out to any old thread; the thread has to have the resource the task needs.

It seems like there should be a concurrency pattern for this, but I can't seem to find it.  I'm implementing this in Python 2 with multiprocessing, so answers in those terms would be great, but a generic solution is fine.  In my case the "threads" are actually separate OS processes and the resources are network connections (and no, it's not a server, so (e)poll/select is not going to help).  In general, a thread/process can hold several resources.

Here is a naive solution: put the tasks in a work queue and turn my thread pool loose on it.  Have each thread check, "Can I do this task?" If yes, do it; if no, put it back in the queue.  However, if each task can only be done by one of N threads, then I'm doing ~2N expensive, wasted accesses to a shared queue just to get one unit of work.

Here is my current thought: have a shared work queue for each resource.  Farm out tasks to the matching queue.  Each thread checks the queue(s) it can handle.

Ideas?

Comment: I have taken the liberty of changing the title; as you say, your threads are not actually threads, so something more general seems appropriate. Solutions might be essentially the same for threads and processes, but there is a mental speedbump (there was for me, at least) in coming to a question about threads and then finding it's not about threads. You might like to re-word the question a little to make it even smoother.

Comment: I think your idea of a queue per resource is good. Workers will need to check multiple queues, which means they can't use blocking reads, and will have to have a priority order on those queues (really, the resources).

Answer (score 0):

A common approach to this is to not allocate resources to threads and queue the appropriate resource in with the data, though I appreciate that this is not always possible if a resource is bound to a particular thread.

The idea of using a queue per resource with threads only popping objects from the queues containing objects it can handle may work.

It may be possible to use a semaphore+concurrentQueue array, indexed by resource, for signaling such threads and also providing a priority system, so eliminating most of the polling and wasteful requeueing.  I will have to think a bit more about that - it kinda depends on how the resources map to the threads.